# Spring-data-jpa A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have searched a quite for the solution, but still no solution yet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Documents {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "doc_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

}

public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "address_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer addressId

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "address_docs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id"))
    private List<Documents> doc;

}

public class Grd {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "grd_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer grdId

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "grd_docs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grd_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id"))
    private List<Documents> doc;

}

public class Person {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grd_id", referencedColumnName = "grd_id")
    private Grd grd;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "address_id")
    private Address address;

}
```

When I put all the data into Person object and save the object it giving me the error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

And based on my solutions I could find I have changed the CascadeType to MERGE for class Address and Grd. But now I am getting the error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fk_address_doc_2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Show us the full code. How are the ids of `Address` and `Grd` declared? Why are you trying to re-use the join table `address_docs` for `Address` and `Grd`?

Comment: @crizzis I have added the ids to the code, they are auto generated. address_docs for Address and Grd was a typo. Corrected this.

Comment: Is the same `Document` by any chance added to both `Address` and `Grd`?   If so, I'd try saving the `Document` first. The error sounds as if you were trying to put duplicates in the `Address.doc` list, though

Comment: @crizzis yes, I am having the same document in Address and Grd, so I do not want to create the duplicate records. I am consuming a 3rd party API to get the data and load them into my db. Please let me know if it would be possible to save the object in one go by calling personRepo.save(person);

Comment: I suspect the problem is that Hibernate treats both documents as new entities, which results in two separate insert statements. It might not be possible to do it in one go; as I said, you could try making all the `Document`s managed first, and only then proceed to save the `Person`

Comment: @crizzis how can I make this managed? I am mapping the data I get from 3rd party API into my entity using dozer.

Comment: Are you sure the list of documents does not contain duplicates (i.e. the ids for the documents are all unique within the list)? If so, `person.getAddress().setDoc(docRepository.save(person.getAddress().getDoc()))` (and a similar line for `person.grd`) should do the trick